# How to get the position of minimum intensity in an image using MATLAB programming

Tags: matlab, image-processing, minimum

I have a image with me. I would like to obtain and mark the position having minimum intensity in that image using MATLAB programming. I would also like to get the value of minimum intensity

Comment: I have the code with me, but for some *reason*, I am not able to share it.

Comment: So do you need any more help?  If not, accepting an answer signifies that you no longer need help.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 3):

To correctly identify **where** in the image the minimum intensity is, combine a call with [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) and [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).  As such, if `A` is your image, do the following:

```
min_val = min(A(:));
[row,col] = find(A == min_val), 1);
```

`min_val` will contain the minimum intensity in your image.  What is important is unrolling the matrix `A` to a single column vector by `A(:)`.  This way, you are ensuring that `min` operates along all of the pixel values at the same time.  In the above code, `row` and `col` will contain the row and column locations of where minimum intensity was found.  The intricacy with this is that if you have more than one pixel that shares the same minimum intensity, `find` will return **all** locations that share this same intensity.  If you just want one of them, append `1` as the second parameter to `find`.

If you want to mark where in the image the minimum intensity is, that's simply done by indexing:

```
A(row,col) = 255;
```

This will set the location of where the minimum intensity is located to be white or 255.

C.Colden's code is also a good attempt, but it will not work if the input is not a vector (i.e. a matrix or array that has more than two dimensions) as `min` will operate along the first non-singleton dimension.  This is why you need to unroll the image into a single vector as in my code above.

If we input a matrix into `min`, in your case, `min` will find the minimum along each column.  If you want, you would have to call `min` twice to ascertain the row location by applying `min` on the column found by the first `min` call but I find the above code more readable.

However, for academic purposes, this is what you would do if you wanted to only use `min`:

```
[min_col, rows] = min(A); %// Find the minimum among all columns as well as which row for each column gave the minimum
[min_val, col] = min(min_col); %// Now, for each of the minimum values, figure out which column gave us the global minimum as well as the minimum itself
row = rows(col); %// Now find the row location of this global minimum
```

As you can see, I would rather stick with the first attempt with `find` and `min`.... it's just more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your image using `imread`(http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html). Afterwards you can treat the image like a matrix. So if "A" is your image, you can use `max` (http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) or `min` to find the values using `Min_Value = min(A(:))`. Afterwards you can search for the location of the Min_Value in your matrix using `[row,column] = find(A == Min_Value)`

Example:

```
A = [3,2,1;4,5,20;7,8,9];
Min_Value = min(A(:));
[row,column]=find(A == Min_Value);
```

Comment: I think that would give you the row index of the min of each column, not the index of the global min.

Comment: @eigenchris - You are certainly correct.

Comment: I agree! I will include the `min(A(:))` in my answer

Comment: In this case `I` will contain the column-major location of where the minimum was found.  If you want the row and column location, consider making a call with `ind2sub` to do that for you: `[row,col] = ind2sub(size(A), I);`

Comment: Good point. However I think the "easiest/simplest" solution for the question is to first find the `min` and then search for it in the matrix. Anyway thanks for the good  `ìnd2sub` example ;)

Comment: Ah that's great. Can you provide how you'd search for where the minimum value is? You only have half of the story!